# Find Files Older than X Days, gzip, create MD5 and remove original

Tags: bash, gzip, md5

I am working on a small script to help me manage a huge selection of log files based on this [Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/471686/how-to-find-files-of-certain-extension-and-tar-each-of-them-in-to-another-locati).

I have added additional requirements I needed:

-Find .log files > 2 day (this was more for a safetly precaution)
-Create MD5 hash of log file
-Remove original log file

```
!/bin/bash
# 1) Find .log files > 2 days
# 2) Determine filename
# 3) gzip filename
# 4) Create gzip MD5
# 5) Remove original file 

function compress_file {
  BASENAME=`/bin/basename "$1"`;
  /bin/gzip -c "$1" > /var/logs/$BASENAME.gz;
  /usr/bin/md5sum  /var/logs/$BASENAME.gz >  /var/logs/$BASENAME.gz.md5
  /bin/rm /var/logs/$BASENAME
}

export -f compress_file;
/bin/find /var/logs -iname "*.log" -mtime +2 -exec /bin/bash -c 'compress_file "$0"' {} \;
export -fn compress_file;
```

As this is a critical operation, I would like to code in some output to a log file (or even send to syslog) for auditing and troubleshooting purposes.

**UPDATE:** in additonal to logging to logger, how can I handle the log files if there where stored by Year/Month/Day since $BASENAME only handles the filename and does not take into consideration of dynamic directories.

```
/var/log//2015/08/10/data1.log
/var/log//2015/08/10/data2.log
/var/log//2015/08/10/data3.log
/var/log//2015/08/11/data1.log
/var/log//2015/08/11/data2.log
/var/log//2015/08/11/data3.log
```

Comment: You can try to get list of empty folders and erase them. Like: find / -type d -empty

Comment: I guess the above soluton is fine with static directory path and need a different approach if using dynamic directory paths what include YYYY/MM/DDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **logger** command to write messages to syslog. Just write log messages before any operation. Like:

```
Logger "Remove $BASENAME"
/bin/rm /var/logs/$BASENAME
```

You can also verify result of your critical commands. Just check "$?" variable after executing any command. It contains result of execution.